# c# On Click Method In CS For A Button And Text Box In CS Using Name?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

1. I'm Trying A small Login universal Windows app.
2. I have LoginPage.xaml and signup button in that.
3. In my LoginPage.xaml.cs file I have signup_click method In that method I have to pass tha signuppage.xaml.
4. Here is my code I'm getting error.

```html
<Page
    x:Class="LoginApp.MainPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LoginApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <!--Title-->
            <TextBlock Text="Login Page" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>

            <!--UserName-->
            <TextBlock Text="UserID" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30"/>
            <TextBox  BorderBrush="LightGray" Name="UserName" GotFocus="UserName_GotFocus"/>

            <!--Password-->
            <TextBlock  Foreground="Black" Text="Password" Margin="9,-7,0,0" FontSize="30"/>
            <PasswordBox BorderBrush="LightGray" Name="PassWord" GotFocus="UserName_GotFocus" />

            <!--Login Button-->
            <Button Content="Login" Background="#FF30DABB" Name="Login" Click="Login_Click" Width="338" />

            <!--  Registration Button-->
            <Button Content="Registration" Background="#FF30DABB" Name="SignUp" Click="SignUp_Click" Width="338"/>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

1. This is my LoginPage.xaml.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace LoginApp.Model
{
    class LoginPage

    {


        public void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {


        }
        public void SiguUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/SignUpPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }


    }
}
```

1. This is my LoginPage.xaml.cs.
2. error is pointing to NavigationService "The name Does not exist in current context".
3. I'm new to c# Don't know The reason for this error.
4. Anyone Help me what is wrong a how to correct this error.
5. I'm Very much thankful to them.

---

1. And in my SignUp.xaml I have a Text Box With the name TxtUserName.
2. In my SignUp.xaml.cs I'm validating the text box with any name.
3. While using this the error message is like "The name txtUsernname does not exist in current context".
4. Below is my code.

```html
<Page
    x:Class="LoginApp.SignUpPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:LoginApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid Margin="10,10,-5,-10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="User Registration :" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="40" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Text="UserName" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,25,0,0"/>
            <TextBox Name="TxtUserName" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.Row="1" Margin="100,0,0,0" GotFocus="Txt_GotFocus"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Password:" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <PasswordBox Name="TxtPwd" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.Row="2" Margin="100,0,0,0" GotFocus="pwd_GotFocus"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Address:" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox Name="TxtAddr" BorderBrush="LightGray" Margin="100,0,0,0" GotFocus="Txt_GotFocus"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Gender:" Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <RadioButton Name="GenMale" Background="LightGray" Grid.Row="4" Margin="100,0,0,0" Content="Male" Foreground="Black"/>
            <RadioButton Name="GenFemale" Background="LightGray" Grid.Row="4" Margin="200,0,0,0" Content="Female" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Phone No:" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox Name="TxtPhNo" Grid.Row="5" Margin="100,0,0,0" Foreground="LightGray" MaxLength="10" InputScope="Digits" GotFocus="Txt_GotFocus"/>
            <TextBlock Text="EmailID:" Grid.Row="6" Margin="0,25,0,0" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox Name="TxtEmail" Grid.Row="6" Margin="100,0,0,0" GotFocus="TxtGotFocus"/>
            <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#FF30DABB" Content="Submit" Name="BtnSubmit" Click="Submit_Click" Grid.Row="7" Margin="0,25.667,0,-41.667" Width="345"/>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

1. This is SignUppage.xaml.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace LoginApp.Model
{
    class SignUpPage
    {

        IsolatedStorageFile ISOFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        public void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(TxtUserName.Text.Trim(), @"^[A-Za-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_\s]*$")) {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName");

            }

        }



    }
}
```

1. This is SignUpPage.xaml.cs
2. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Did you forget to use the correct reference? try: `using System.Windows.Navigation;` MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigate(v=vs.110).aspx Add reference to `PresentationFramework.dll`

Comment: Using directive is unnecessary .The name Navigation Does not exist in the  namespace System.windows@SebastianSchulz

Comment: I added reference to `PresentationFramework.dll` and my using does work and shows no error.

Comment: where i can find the PresentationFramework.dll??

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE I browse through path but i'm unable to locate it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/9DTk06I

Comment: No Framework assemblies were found on the machine

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well all your code, you have separate yours *.xaml (in /Views) et yours *.xaml.cs (in /Model).

I recommend you to put yours .xaml and .xaml.cs together in Views because *.xaml.cs is not a Model but the code behind. A model is more of an element of your database (roughly).

Then, your *.xaml.cs should be implementing System.Windows.Controls.Page, this is an exemple :

```
public partial class LoginPage : Page
```

Also don't forget to create the constructor (but normally if you use the file creator of Visual Studio, it will create the skeleton for the file you want to create) :

```
public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Finally if with that it is still not working, be sure that you are using the right references as Sebastian Schulz told you.